# Keycloak integration with SpringDoc and spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, springdoc-openapi-ui

App stack: Spring boot / Spring Doc / Keycloak

I am trying to integrate the above stack together, everything works well till I am using keycloak policy enforcement.

At the bringing the app is running and I can access the Swagger UI served thanks to spring doc, but after like 20 or 30 seconds, I got HTTP ERROR 401 while I am trying to access the exact link of swagger and keycloak refuse all access to any URL or rest API

Console Error:

```
2022-05-22 23:31:55.650 DEBUG 92263 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html
2022-05-22 23:31:55.650 DEBUG 92263 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : checkCorsPreflight http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html
2022-05-22 23:31:55.651 DEBUG 92263 --- [io-8080-exec-10] .k.a.t.AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke /swagger-ui/index.html
2022-05-22 23:31:55.651 DEBUG 92263 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html
2022-05-22 23:31:55.651 DEBUG 92263 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Origin: null uri: http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html
2022-05-22 23:31:55.651 DEBUG 92263 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : cors validation not needed as we are not a secure session or origin header was null: http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html
2022-05-22 23:31:55.651 DEBUG 92263 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.k.a.authorization.PolicyEnforcer       : Policy enforcement is enabled. Enforcing policy decisions for path [http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html].
2022-05-22 23:31:55.917 DEBUG 92263 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.k.a.authorization.PolicyEnforcer       : Policy enforcement result for path [http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html] is : DENIED
2022-05-22 23:31:55.917 DEBUG 92263 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.k.a.authorization.PolicyEnforcer       : Returning authorization context with permissions:
2022-05-22 23:31:55.917 DEBUG 92263 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2022-05-22 23:31:55.917 DEBUG 92263 --- [io-8080-exec-10] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-05-22 23:31:55.917 DEBUG 92263 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://localhost:8080/error
2022-05-22 23:31:55.917 DEBUG 92263 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : checkCorsPreflight http://localhost:8080/error
2022-05-22 23:31:55.917 TRACE 92263 --- [io-8080-exec-10] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/sso/login'], RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=Authorization, expectedHeaderValue=null], org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.QueryParamPresenceRequestMatcher@1eab2ee7, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.AdapterStateCookieRequestMatcher@2ad76210]
2022-05-22 23:31:55.918 DEBUG 92263 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2022-05-22 23:31:55.918 DEBUG 92263 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /error] with attributes [authenticated]
2022-05-22 23:31:55.918 DEBUG 92263 --- [io-8080-exec-10] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

My policy enforcement to swagger links here is my keycloak YAML file

```
keycloak:
  realm: phelix
  auth-server-url: https://keycloak-server-url/auth
  ssl-required: none
  resource: orders
  use-resource-role-mappings: true
  bearer-only: true
  cors-exposed-headers: X-Total-Count
  cors: true
  principal-attribute: preferred_username
  credentials:
    secret: 111-111-111.....
  policy-enforcer-config:
    enforcement-mode: ENFORCING
    lazy-load-paths: true
    paths:
      - path: /swagger-ui/*.html
        enforcement-mode: DISABLED
      - path: /actuator/*
        enforcement-mode: DISABLED
      - path: /swagger-ui/*
        enforcement-mode: DISABLED
      - path: /swagger-ui.html
        enforcement-mode: DISABLED
      - path: /v3/api-docs/*
        enforcement-mode: DISABLED
```

Security config class which extends keycloak adapter

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "security.config.use-keycloak", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "keycloak")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:keycloak-configs.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] WHITELIST_URLS = {
            "/v3/api-docs/**",
            "/swagger-ui/**",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/actuator/**",
    };
    public KeycloakClientRequestFactory keycloakClientRequestFactory;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(WHITELIST_URLS).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        SimpleAuthorityMapper mapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
        mapper.setPrefix("");
        authenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(mapper);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy(); //for bearer-only services
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakDeployment keycloakDeploymentBuilder(KeycloakSpringBootProperties configuration) {
        return KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(configuration);
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public KeycloakRestTemplate keycloakRestTemplate() {
        return new KeycloakRestTemplate(keycloakClientRequestFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public AccessToken getAccessToken() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof KeycloakPrincipal) {
            return ((KeycloakPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal()).getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken();
        } else {
            return new AccessToken();
        }
    }
}
```

Dependencies:

```
'springboot': '2.7.0'
'keycloakVersion': '16.1.0'
'springdoc-openapi-ui': '1.6.8'
```

Any thoughts ?